# Simple mathematical errors in SQL (not a recognized table hints option)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having the following error:
is not a recognized table hints option. if it is intended as a parameter to a table valued function, ensure that your database capability is set to 90

from the below code

```
select*from dbo.customerpurchases
with
(termlystartdate-examdate/365) AS [ID Length]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? WITH after the table name is used for hints to the sql server query processor, and I think you may be trying to just do a select.

Comment: minus the exam date from the termly start date and divide it by 365

Comment: in that case, Rigerta's answer should do it, except you might want to change where the parentheses are. It's always useful to add your intention in the question, not just the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (termlystartdate-examdate/365) as IdLength, *
from dbo.customerpurchases
```

It would be better if you specified column names instead of using `select *`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select (termlystartdate-examdate)/365 as IdLength
from dbo.customerpurchases
```